# php extract associate arrays

Tags: php, arrays

There is an array which is hold the dynamic data. it changes randomly. I used `foreach()` loop to retrieve the `["space"]` `["channel"]` and `["Parker Dial String"]`.

```
$parking_lot = array
(
    0 => "bellcab-parked-call",
    2 => "Parking Extension   :  300",
    3 => "Parking Context     :  bellcab_call_parking_lot",
    4 => "Parking Spaces      :  3000-3099",
    5 => "Parking Time        :  0 sec",
    6 => "Comeback to Origin  :  no",
    7 => "Comeback Context    :  bellcab-parked-call-return",
    8 => "Comeback Dial Time  :  30 sec",
    9 => "MusicOnHold Class   :  ",
    10 => "Enabled             :  yes",
    11 => "Dynamic             :  no",
    12 => "",
    13 => "Parked Calls",
    14 => "------------",
    15 =>  "Space               :  3000",
    16 =>  "Channel             :  SIP/itc-vitel-inbound-00000ee4",
    17 =>  "Parker Dial String  :  3004",
    18 => "",
    19 =>   "Space               :  3001",
    20 =>   "Channel             :  SIP/itc-vitel-inbound-00000ee7",
    21 =>   "Parker Dial String  :  3004",
    22 =>   "Space               :  3002",
    23 =>   "Channel             :  SIP/itc-vitel-inbound-00000e82",
    24 =>   "Parker Dial String  :  3004",
    25 => "",
    26 => "",
    27 => "--END COMMAND--"
);

foreach($parking_lot as $val)
{
    $temp = explode(" : ", $val);
    if(isset($temp[1])){
        $new_array[trim($temp[0])][] = trim($temp[1]);
    }
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [Parking Extension] => Array
        (
            [0] => 300
        )

    [Parking Context] => Array
        (
            [0] => bellcab_call_parking_lot
        )

    [Parking Spaces] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3000-3099
        )

    [Parking Time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0 sec
        )

    [Comeback to Origin] => Array
        (
            [0] => no
        )

    [Comeback Context] => Array
        (
            [0] => bellcab-parked-call-return
        )

    [Comeback Dial Time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30 sec
        )

    [MusicOnHold Class] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
        )

    [Enabled] => Array
        (
            [0] => yes
        )

    [Dynamic] => Array
        (
            [0] => no
        )

    [Space] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3000
            [1] => 3001
            [2] => 3002
        )

    [Channel] => Array
        (
            [0] => SIP/itc-vitel-inbound-00000ee4
            [1] => SIP/itc-vitel-inbound-00000ee7
            [2] => SIP/itc-vitel-inbound-00000e82
        )

    [Parker Dial String] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3004
            [1] => 3004
            [2] => 3004
        )

)
```

The desired output is like this

```
Array
(
   Array(
         [Space] => 3000
         [Channel] => SIP/itc-vitel-inbound-00000ee4
         [Parker Dial String] => 3004
        )
   Array(
         [Space] => 3001
         [Channel] => SIP/itc-vitel-inbound-00000ee7
         [Parker Dial String] => 3004
        )
   Array(
         [Space] => 3002
         [Channel] => SIP/itc-vitel-inbound-00000e82
         [Parker Dial String] => 3004
        )
)
```

Comment: If it changes randomly how can you specify any pattern to extract values of of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter the array you have  to be with only the desire keys.

Then use [array-map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to group them (notice the use of the `...` operator to flat the array):

```
$keys = array("Space", "Channel", "Parker Dial String");
foreach($keys as $k)
    $filtered[] = $new_array[$k];
$res = array_map(null, ...$filtered);
$res = array_map(function ($e) use ($keys) {return array_combine($keys, $e);}, $res);
print_r($res);
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/o4Cij)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility:

1. Define the keys you want.

   ```
   $keys = ['Space', 'Channel', 'Parker Dial String'];
   ```
2. Extract them from your `$new_array` array using `array_intersect_key`.

   ```
   $values = array_values(array_intersect_key($new_array, array_flip($keys)));
   ```
3. Map `array_combine` over the result using array unpacking to get your desired result.

   ```
   $result = array_map(
       function(...$values) use ($keys) { return array_combine($keys, $values); },
       ...$values
   );
   ```

`array_values` is necessary in the second step because you can't unpack arrays with string keys. You could move it to the third step instead with `...array_values($values)` instead of `...$values` if you prefer.

Comment: Great mind and all... - but I think your is better - I used the `array_map` twice and you only once as you use the better advantage of the `...`

Comment: @dWinder It actually occurred to me recently when I was answering another question here and it was one of those things that seemed obvious in hindsight. I had gotten used to using `array_map(null, ` with multiple arrays before the splat operator existed, and it took me until just last week to notice you could do the same thing in one step.

Comment: Thanks guys. it is replacing the ["Channel"] with ["Space"].

Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Space] => SIP/itc-vitel-inbound-00000ee4
            [Channel] => 3000
            [Parker Dial String] => 3004
        )
 )